# I have to use item.item.property in renderItem of a FlatList intead of item.property

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I have this code

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.music_genres}
    extraData={this.state}
    renderItem={(genre) => (
        <ListItem>
            <CheckBox
                onPress={this.onGenreChange.bind(this, item.item, genre.item.id)}
                checked={this.eventHasGenre(item.item, genre.item.id) > -1 ? true : false} />
            <Body>
                <Text>{genre.item.name}</Text>
            </Body>
        </ListItem>
    )}
/>
```

It works, but as you can see I have to use "genre.item.id" (or "genre.item.name") instead of simply "genre.id".
If I change the renderItem in (like doc says to do)

```
renderItem={({genre}) => ( // look brackets around "genre"
```

And I try with

```
...
<Text>{genre.name}</Text>
...
```

I get this error

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

This is the value of this.state.music_genres

```
[{…}]
0: {id: 7, name: "Swing", plural: null, language: "it", genre_type: "music"}
length: 1
```

Why I can not use "genre.id"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `({genre})` because this is a object destructuring. In this param will come a object (passed by react) with an attribute `item`, like this:

```
obj : { item: {...}}
```

so when you're trying to get `genre` from this `obj`, you only will get undefined because there is no genre in this object param.

Just do `renderItem={({item}) => (` and use `item.id` and you'll be good.

Comment: Ok, thx for explanation. What about a List inside a List? I would have 2 "item" variable.

Comment: I can't see this List inside List. But I think you can change the name of "item" variable in the paren List.

Comment: If I change name in the parent List I have the same problem of the nested List. Or I miss something?

Comment: They both are a FlatList type?

Comment: Yes, they are of the same FlatList type.

Comment: You can "rename" the destructuring in seconte FlatList like this "renderItem={({item:itemB}) => (" and using "itemB.id"